# How to add a permission : reorder Taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, users

I need some roles to be able to edit and add terms of specific vocabularies, **but not to reorder them**. How can I add the permission **reorder *foo* vocabulary terms, reorder *bar* vocabulary terms...** with a module or programmatically ?

AFAIK edit terms permissions immediately give you the permissions to reorder terms also.

I already tried these modules below but none implements such permission.

[Vocabulary Permissions Per Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/vppr)

> Allows adding to/editing terms of/removing terms from vocabularies per
> role... adding terms to a vocabulary but not to another, **reordering**/editing terms of a vocabulary but not another's, etc.

Says so, but reordering /editing come together.

[Taxonomy access fix](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access_fix)

> - adds 1 permission per vocabulary: "add terms in X"
> - changes the way vocabulary specific permissions are handled
> - changes the Taxonomy admin pages' access checks
> - alters the vocabularies overview table to show only what you have access to edit or delete
>
> The module does what native Taxonomy lacks: more specific Taxonomy
> permissions (and checking them correctly).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging a bit more into permission implementation, this is how I solved this issue, in combination with [Taxonomy access fix](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access_fix).

```
/**
 * Implements hook_permission();
 */
function MYMODULE_permission() {
  return array(
    'reorder_taxonomy_terms' => array(
      'title' => t('Reorder taxonomy terms'),
      'description' => t('Allows users to reorder taxonomy terms.'),
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_js_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_js_alter(&$javascript) {
  if (!user_access('reorder_taxonomy_terms')) {
    unset($javascript['misc/tabledrag.js']);
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter();
 */
function MYMODULE_form_taxonomy_overview_terms_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  global $user;
  if (!user_access('reorder_taxonomy_terms')) {
    foreach($form as $k=>$v){
      if(substr($k, 0, 3) == 'tid'){ 
        unset($form[$k]['weight']);
      }
    }
    unset($form['actions']['reset_alphabetical']);
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module','vts_taxonomy_permissions').'/MYMODULE.css');

  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_FORM_ID_alter();
 */
function MYMODULE_form_taxonomy_form_term_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  global $user; 
  if (!user_access('reorder_taxonomy_terms')){
    unset($form['relations']['weight']);
  }
}
```

In MYMODULE.css

```
/* Hide reorder help text */
#block-system-help {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement hook_form_alter  and remove the `Sort alphabetically` button based on the role.

Edit: Something like this (tested)

```
function mymod_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (in_array('userrole', $user->roles) && ($form_id == 'taxonomy_overview_terms') {
    unset($form['actions']['reset_alphabetical']);
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module','mymod').'/css/mymod.css');
  }
}
```

and in `css/mymod.css`, do

```
.handle,.tabledrag-toggle-weight {display:none;}
```

This hides the `Reset to alphabetical` button, drag handles, and `Show row weights` link.

Comment: Thank you. What about the drag and drop UI to reorder almost anything in Drupal including taxonomy terms ? And its alter ego "show row weight" ?

Comment: You can also use hook_form_alter for that.

Comment: @Kojo I updated my answer.

Comment: @Kojo Edits should not change an answer's code in a radical way. If you have better code, write your own answer.

Comment: Thanks Kartagis, for this turn around. By the way, anybody with Firebug or similar could reorder the terms anyway. I posted another solution which really _gives or not_ a permission to reorder vocabulary terms